# Prove that the Fourier series of $\frac{1}{f}$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-series, banach-algebras

I have a problem:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on the unit circle $(\Gamma)$:
>
> $$\Gamma=\{e^{i\theta}: \theta\in [0, 2 \pi]\}$$
>
> Assume that $f \ne 0$ on $\Gamma$, and the **Fourier series** of $f$ is *absolutely convergent* on $\Gamma$.
>
> Prove that the **Fourier series** of $\dfrac{1}{f}$ is *absolutely convergent* on $\Gamma$.

=================================================

- I've tried to use the definition of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is **absolutely convergent**:

> A real or complex series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is said to *converge absolutely* if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left|a_n\right| = L$ for some real number $L$.

- And use the definition of the [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)

So let the **Fourier series** of $f$ be given by:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}e^{in \theta}$$

We want to show that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_{n}e^{in \theta}| \to f(\theta)< +\infty$$

==========================================

But I still have no solution :( . Can anyone help me!

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: A pretty proof was given by Gelfand http://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/shk/public_html/wiener1.pdf

Comment: Yes, It's great link! thanks **ABC**. I'll write it here, Please you check my post.

Comment: Since the **theorem** $3.1$, we have $\lambda - f$ is invertible. But I think that we need to show the **Theorem 1.1. (Wiener’s Theorem)** (in your link)??? How can we show it? Thanks!

Comment: In that note, the very last paragraph is what would be the proof of Theorem 1.1. After all the work, the proof reduces to: If $f$ is not invertible there is a non-zero functional $\phi$ such that $\phi(f)=0$. All the functionals in this algebra are evaluations at certain point, so $0=\phi(f)=f(t_0)$ for some $t_0$, contradiction.

Comment: Oh, yes, Thanks **ABC** the last paragraph..., I'm sorry when I forgot reading it. The first We show that **Theorem 3.1**, the **Corollary 3.2**, the **Corollary 3.3**, the **Corollary 3.5**, the **Proposition 3.6** and rewrite the second your post. OMG, hic hic :( It's too long........

Comment: Yes, it is not a simple proof (if you begin from scratch). Direct proofs, which existed before Gelfand's, are not so simple either. There are many direct proofs. Online, you can find many searching for 'Weiner's theorem'.

Comment: Thank you very much **ABC**! I'll use your great link! Nice to get acquainted with you.

Comment: @ABC, may be you can collect ll these comments into the single answer?

Comment: yes, I think so. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard proof ever since Gelfand uses commutative Banach agebras, but this requires a certain amount of preparations. A short proof was given by Newman in 1975. The paper is only two pages long, but still too long to summarize. Anyway, the paper is accessible freely at
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-048-01/S0002-9939-1975-0365002-8/S0002-9939-1975-0365002-8.pdf

Comment: Thanks **M. Mueger**! It's very useful to me.

Comment: In Newman's proof: $$\sum_{n \ne 0}n^2|a_n|^2=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f'(x)|^2 \rm d x$$
 
I think that we use the [Parseval's theorem]
We apply for $$A(x)=B(x)=f'(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(ina_n)\cdot e^{inx}$$ then $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(ina_n)\overline{(ina_n)}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f'(x) \overline{f'(x)} \rm d x$$ Whence $$\sum_{n \ne 0}n^2|a_n|^2=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f'(x)|^2 \rm d x$$
Do I have the correct change?
[Parseval's theorem]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem

Comment: Yes, this the way to prove it.

Comment: This is one of my favorite papers! I thought is was strange N. Wiener did not see that.